# Python: how to add a @classmethod @property.setter

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

This is a follow up question of [Python: how to sum/multiply an int with the value of a @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76038102/python-how-to-sum-multiply-an-int-with-the-value-of-a-property/76038184#76038184)

In the initial question I wanted to do arythmetic operations on the value of a property (which was related to a class attribute); I found out I had to define the property as a classmethod.

Now suppose I want to be able to change that property too, like in:

```
class A:
    __att = 3
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def att(cls):
        return cls.__att
    
    """
    @classmethod
    @att.setter
    def att(cls, val):
        cls.__att = val
    """
    
    @classmethod
    def changeAtt(cls, val):
        cls.__att = val
        
    def test_method(self):
        return 3*A.att
        
a = A()
a.att = 5 #adding "att" to instance
print(a.test_method())
a.changeAtt(5)
print(a.test_method())
```

Output is

```
9
15
```

Tha method `changeAtt` do what I want, so it is something possible to accomplish, but if I try to uncomment the property setter, I get an error:

`@att.setter AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute 'setter'`

I also tried to invert the order of decorators, with no result.
Again: what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As chepner mentioned there are some restrictions in python to use @property with @classmethod and @xxx.setter.

but there is a workaround using meta classes:

```py
class MyMetaClass(type):
    __att = 8

    @property
    def att(cls):
        return cls.__att

    @att.setter
    def att(cls, value):
        cls.__att = value

class A(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    pass


print(A.att)
```

this is working fine in python 3.10 and 3.11

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks. Although I just want to clearify, should we use cls or self inside MyMetaClass as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740701/7074112 Although both cls and self are working perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

In short, `att` is not a property; it's a class method. It simply doesn't have a `setter` method to use as a decorator to add a setter. Reversing the order of the decorators doesn't work because `classmethod` objects themselves are not callable; only the thing a `classmethod`'s `__get__` method *returns* is callable.

One could get around this by not using `property` as a decorator, but passing it two arguments explicitly with something like

```
class A:
    __att = 3
    
    @classmethod
    def att_getter(cls):
        return cls.__att
    
    @classmethod
    def att_setter(cls, val):
        cls.__att = val

    att = property(att_getter, att_setter)
    del att_getter, att_setter
    
    ...
```

but there is another problem. Reversing the order of the decorators, or not using `property` as a decorator at all, doesn't work because `classmethod` objects themselves are not callable; only the thing a `classmethod`'s `__get__` method *returns* is callable.

`classmethod` is a non-data descriptor; it has only a `__get__` method, so while you can *retrieve* whatever the class method wraps with something like `A.att`, there is no `__set__` method (which a data descriptor like `property` has) to define what `A.att = ...` means.

Further, even the ability to mimic how one would imagine a "class property" to behave is due to a deprecated-as-of-Python-3.11 code path in `classmethod.__get__` which causes `A.att` to "recursively" invoke the `__get__` method of whatever `A.__dict__['att'].__get__` would return. You can define what amounts to a read-only class property for now by composing `classmethod` and `property`, but it's my understanding this will not work in a future version of Python.